# How can I cancel and delete OS Software update of Andoroid KitKat?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, updates

[image: Android KitKat OS Software update information]

Initially I would like to update my Android OS from KitKat to Lollipop. Unfortunately, it will decrease around 950MB it internal memory/RAM. Then I decided will not continue to update it. But, how can I canceled it and delete all the dawnloaded files (548.71MB of OS software)? Only INSTALL button available.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to factory reset your device in order to delete the downloaded OS.
As it was downloaded with intention to install, So I don't think there's any other way to delete it (other than rooting and finding it).

Comment: 'system' is mounted read-only. Downloaded updates are written to `/data` or possibly `/cache`. Factory reset also doesn't touch `/system`.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that. Edited my answer. Thanks

Comment: That very horrifying if I can not cancel it. If I have to continue to install, it will make my phone very slow.

Comment: I believe software updates don't consume all of your internal storage space. There must be at least 1GB of it left for user. This should not slow the device anyways.
if you still don't want to install the update, you will have to factory reset it.